# How to start with boot disk selection without access to Apple keyboard

Tags: macos, boot

I am trying to install from a bootable USB containing an installer for Mac OS X El Capitan on a Mac Mini. Normally I would hold Option while booting to gain access to a screen where I can select from the bootable USB or the internal hard drive (or any other bootable disks). The problem is that I don't currently have access to an Apple keyboard.

I have tried setting the USB to the bootable volume using `bless`, but that doesn't boot into the installer.

Is there a way to force the machine to boot to that selection? Perhaps certain boot flags could be set using the `nvram` command. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a generic USB keyboard rather than an Apple one, you can hold `Alt` to perform the same action as holding `Option` on an Apple keyboard. Likewise, holding the Windows key will perform the same action as holding `Command`.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. The particular Windows keyboard I had attached never initiated any input during the startup. I ended up picking up an Apple keyboard at the store.

Comment: This works, but instead of holding the Alt key, you have to Repeatedly press and release the Alt key until boot select shows up